# Get all rows of 1 table in join

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables of which I join, I want to get all results of table 2 but once I add a condition of table 1 it will naturally filter out rows from table 2 even though it is left join, how can I get all rows of table 2 in this case?

```
select b.ID, count(*) from  [Table2] b
left  join [Table1] a on a.ID=b.ID
where a.created between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-16'
group by b.ID
```

Comment: This has been asked multiple times here, move the condition: `a.created between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-16'` to the ON clause.

Comment: `coalesce()` to convert `b.ID is null` rows into a value, THEN do the group by on this subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @forpas says place the predicate in the `ON` clause:

```
select b.ID, count(*) from  [Table2] b
left  join [Table1] a on a.ID=b.ID
                     and a.created between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-16'
group by b.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `where` condition turns the `left join` into an `inner join`.  Why?  Because the value of `a.created` is `NULL` and that fails the `where` condition.

I want to suggest a correlated subquery instead:

```
select b.ID, 
       (select count(*)
        from [Table1] a 
        where a.ID = b.ID and
              a.created between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-16'
      )
from [Table2] b;
```

This avoids the outer aggregation and with an index on `Table1(id, created)` is likely to have better performance than one using the aggregation.